# Passing empty cells to sql-server shows "0" instead of NULL

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm passing values from Excel to sql-server via stored procedure.
There are two columns in Excel in where the cells contain integers or are empty.
But in sql-server, the empty cells from one column are shown as NULL, and the empty cells from the other are shown as "0". Why is that? Both variables are declared as integers in vba, and in sql.

What do I have to do to get everywhere NULL if the cell is empty?

This is part of the vba-code:

```
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim query As String
Global ktghnev As String
Global ktghID As Integer
Dim elsosor As Integer
Dim pt, bank As Integer
Dim fizmod As String
Dim honap As String

With ActiveSheet
elsosor = 3

Do Until .Cells(elsosor, 1) = ""
nevID = .Cells(elsosor, 1)
pt = .Cells(elsosor, 4)
bank = .Cells(elsosor, 5)


 If IsEmpty(Range("D" & elsosor)) = False Or IsEmpty(Range("E" & elsosor)) = False Then


Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "EURfeltoltes"
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@nevID", adInteger, adParamInput, , nevID)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@ktghID", adInteger, adParamInput, , ktghID)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@honap", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, honap)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@pt", adInteger, adParamInput, , pt)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@bank", adInteger, adParamInput, , bank)
cmd.Execute

End If

elsosor = elsosor + 1


Loop
End With
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EURfeltoltes] 
@nevID int = null, 
@ktghID int = null,
@honap nvarchar(10) = null,
@pt int = null,
@bank int = null
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
insert into bertabla (nevID, ktghelyID, honap, eurpt, eurbank) values (@nevID, @ktghID, @honap, @pt, @bank)
END
```

Comment: Empty (`''`) and *`NULL`* are not synonyms. The latter is effectively an unknown value, it's not an empty string. If you want to use the default values on an SP, don't pass the parameter.

Comment: What are the specs on the column you are inserting into? Any default constraints?

Comment: What is the cell formatting / cell datatype in Excel?

Comment: Meanwhile I realised that I was declaring the variables in a wrong way. Dim pt, bank as integer is incorrect. If I change it to Dim pt as integer, bank as integer, it gives "0" to both columns if a cell is empty. If the variables are declared as variants, it gives NULL to the sql server. I wanted to use integer, but I need rather NULL-s in the server, so I guess I have to be happy with variants :)

Comment: I agree with Larnu here. You should not pass the parameters that are empty string in Excel. That is a better approach than using variants. A simple if around each parameter in your VBA would be sufficient.

Comment: I tried that too. But if I have a value in the first row and and empty cell in the next row, the parameter will keep the last given value. I tried to set the variable to default at the end of the cycle, but if the parameter is an integer, I cant do that. If its a variant, then I can set it to nothing, but then I'm at the same place as now.